# No contracted notice period?

Tags: resignation, human-resources, united-kingdom, notice-period

I have worked with my current employer in the UK for well over a decade and I have decided I need to leave (a point which is not up for discussion in this forum).

I've looked through my contract and all written correspondence and nowhere does it mention a minimum notice period. Not once.

I am paid an annual salary monthly, so logic dictates I should give a month's notice. HOWEVER...

Everyone who leaves is told by the personnel department that they should work a month's notice. But the personnel department consists of one individual, and there is nothing in writing regarding a notice period. When I asked (without saying why) the notice period is one month, the answer was 'because it's procedure' and when I pressed further I was politely asked to leave.

Now, I've had numerous problems with the personnel department previously (see my previous question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57563/being-singled-out-for-pay-deductions) if you're interested in one example) and I don't want to leave on a particularly hostile note.

So I guess my question is, is there a 'standard' notice period for monthly paid employees in the UK? If there isn't, and with nothing in writing, is there anything to stop me giving two weeks notice instead? Or even to the extreme, is there anything to stop me giving notice and just walking out? Not that I would do that - I might have no respect for the personnel department or the business anymore but I do respect and value my departmental colleagues.

Comment: This could be a useful question but needs to be reworded with most of the personal backstory cut to be worth keeping open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UK, there are two types of notice period; contractual, and statutory.

Contractual notice is that set in any contract. You've checked your contract, and there's nothing in there, so it won't apply. I assume you've checked your employment handbook also?

Statutory notice, if *you* decide to leave after you've worked at a company for more than a month, is one week. It doesn't change/get any longer based on how long you've worked there. If the company decides to make you redundant, they have to give notice of (or pay) one week for each year of service.

If you have any holiday this year accrued, take it off your notice period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - though I've never heard of an employment handbook... I don't think this place is that organised! I'm going to have to see what other 'unsaid' agreements might be in place.

Comment: 'unsaid' agreements aren't worth the paper they're written on... :)

Comment: I don't know that I would personally take holiday off my notice period.  I'm American, so maybe things are different here.  I'd look into the laws about all that before deciding what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are some UK standards, look at this:

[Handing in your notice: UK Gov](https://www.gov.uk/handing-in-your-notice/giving-notice)

It seems to suggest you must give at least one weeks notice.

I seem to remember (but IANAL) that your employer can have a standard contract of employment which can state notice period, and even if you didn't explicitly get a copy it still may apply, I'd ask at the citizen's advice for clarification.  Some info on this is here:

[Contract terms: UK Gov](https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions/contract-terms)

> 2. Contract terms
>      The legal parts of a contract are known as ‘terms’. An employer should make clear which parts of a contract are legally binding.
>
>    Contract terms could be:
>
>    - in a written contract, or similar document like a written statement of employment
>    - verbally agreed
>    - in an employee handbook or on a company notice board
>    - in an offer letter from the employer
>    - required by law (eg an employer must pay employees at least the National Minimum Wage)
>    - in collective agreements - negotiated agreements between employers and trade unions or staff associations
>    - implied terms - automatically part of a contract even if they’re not written down

So they could possibly argue that as they have told you it was 4 weeks, and you've never disputed that, it's a verbal agreement.

Comment: Give me the good old USA, where I can (and have) told a manager to perform an anatomically impossible act, turned in my keys and walked out mid-shift.

Comment: For some reason I didn't even think the government would have advice on this - thank you. I'll check regarding the standard contract too.

Comment: @RichardU - it works both ways, they have to give you notice as well, so you can't just turn up one day to find you're out the door.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Your quote from Contract Terms basically means that the business can do what they want, as even if it's not written down they can claim that the agreement was implied or verbally agreed even if it wasn't (or was agreed by people who are no longer with the company), if I'm reading it correctly?

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager and that's happened too.  But they did me a favor.

Comment: @Lyall - you'd need to talk to the citizen's advice (free) or a lawyer, I'm not qualified to give you that kind of advice, only point you at it!

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager And I very much appreciate the pointing! Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Lyall on that page it talks about implied terms, I think it's quite specific on what can be implied, it's not a get-out-of-jail free card for the employer

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Thanks - I'll have a proper read through

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager "Citizen's advice"?  Maybe we'll put something like that together in America...in another 200 years or so.

Comment: @BobRodes - see what your missing here: https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk  Its a non-profit which dispenses low level  advice to anyone in the UK, both legal and other.  They cover most things from consumer and employment law to benefits and tax advice, even relationship advice!

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager I'd go and look, but I don't think I could stand the pain.  :)  I lived in England as a teenager for a couple of years (2nd and 3rd form) back in the early 70's.  So I've and seen you Brits warts and all, and seen ourselves from your perspective.  I take care of a disabled person, so I'm a bit sensitive to our American tendency to lionize those of ourselves who are more interested in service to themselves than to their fellows, which allows them to find so much opportunity to pursue that interest in our health, legal and governmental systems to the detriment of society.